# "Remember me" always on in Symfony 2 without configuring it?

Tags: symfony, authentication, configuration, remember-me

I am doing a Admin Panel in Symfony 2. I created the login form, the firewall and the backend controllers and everything runs absolutely fine except the remember me functionality on the site. It is always on whether the checkbox "Remember me" is clicked or not.

Here is my configuration:

```
**config.yml**
    session:
        handler_id:  ~
        cookie_lifetime: 86400
        gc_maxlifetime: 1800

**security.yml**
security:
    firewalls:
        admin_area:
            pattern: /admin/
            context: admin
            anonymous:  ~
            form_login:
                username_parameter: "admin_login[username]"
                password_parameter: "admin_login[password]"
                csrf_parameter: "admin_login[_token]"
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
                intention: authentication
                login_path: /admin/login
                check_path: /admin/login_check
                success_handler: admin_login_success_handler
                remember_me: true
            logout:
                path:   /admin/logout
                target: /admin/
            remember_me:
                remember_me_parameter: "admin_login[remember_me]"
                key:      "admin_secret"
                lifetime: 86400
                path:     /admin/
                domain:   ~

    access_control:
        - { path: /admin/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: /admin/([a-z_]+)?, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

The Remember me checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="admin_login_remember_me" name="admin_login[remember_me]" value="1">
```

Am I doing something wrong in this setup so whether the checkbox is selected or not I always get true on running this in the controllers:

```
$this->get('security.context')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED')
```

and if I close the browser and reopen it even if "Remember me" was unchecked on the last login I am still logged in the admin panel.

Any comments will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you close your browser ? To test, you should process logout. Logging out should erase REMEMBERME cookie...

Comment: Isn't the remember me functionality supposed to keep the user logged in even when the browser is closed and reopened again (thus having the session restarted)?

Comment: Session is not necessarly restarted when browser is closed and re-started. And IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED is an authentication level between IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY (session started, not logged) and IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY (logged from credentials). So if a user is logged from a form, it will be granted IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED... Check your cookie instead of checking this fake role.

Comment: I checked. The cookied REMEMBERME works fine - when checkbox is checked it is there, when unchecked it is not. When logged out, it is errased. Maybe what I am trying to achieve is not possible by this default remember me functionality. I want to have the user login with remember me checked and when the browser is closed and reopened later to have the logged state kept (based on the remember me expiration time) but if unchecked, when the browser is closed the user to be logged out (i.e session to be killed) - is that thing possible with the config or I should write a event listener for it?

Comment: You can not force session kill on browser closing. It's even not possible from server side.

Comment: I got the solution! What I meant was to have the session expire upon browser close. According to the doc (http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/session_configuration.html#session-cookie-lifetime) - the cookie_lifetime should be set to 0 with my current config and this does the trick :)

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same issue. But in my `config.yml` I have the following :  `cookie_lifetime: 0` on `session` on `framework`. After hours, I still can't manage to understand why it doesn't work. Do you do anything else ?